# can i get more zoom on a google engine map

Tags: satellite, satellite-image

hello i need a map for year 2002 for a specific Latitude / Longitude  , when i was searching i found that only Landsat was doing capturing since 1984 , i searched a lot and found google engine maps for the place which i need (2006 year was good) but need 2002 which is not possible even in google earth software
here's a picture which shows my problem (right  zoom is what i need , left zoom is what i've found)

[image]

Comment: So what is your objective? To get a Landsat image of your place in 2002?

Comment: it's a Civil Engineering Office which need such a picture for a Research they are doing on that land in years 2002 and below but 2002 matters very much as they told